# Css espaçamento entre os elementos flex

Tags: css, html5, css3, flexbox

Olá, 
alguém que me pode ajudar a construir uma grid estática se é que lhe possa chamar isso:
O que quero é poder adicionar 3 blocos por row estes com um tamanho fixo igual, com tendência a crescer na vertical. E aplicar as margens como é mostrado na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém me pode dar uma ajuda?

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    Box1
  </div>
  
  <div class="box">
    Box1
  </div>
  
  <div class="box">
    Box1
  </div>
  
  <div class="box">
    Box1
  </div>
  
  <div class="box">
    Box1
  </div>
  
  <div class="box">
    Box1
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cara sua pergunta não esta muito clara, se quer raminho fixo de 100px pro box e tamanho fixo de 300px pro container, como vc quer que ele cresça na horizontal? O container sempre vai ter 300px ou ele vai ter no mínimo 300px podendo aumentar? E o box, o tamanho mínimo dele deve ser 100px podendo aumentar caso o container cresça tbm?

Comment: Colapso, o que queria dizer era, crescer na vertical, o Container vai ter sempre 3 elementos por row na horizontal (3 de 100px = 300px). O tamanho do box adapta-se consoante os seus filhos. Deu para esclarecer?

Comment: Então ele não vai crescer na horizontal, vai crescer ao na vertical? O box sempre vai ter 100px da largura, mas.pode ter 200px de altura por exemplo?

Comment: Simprificando, não quero saber de tamanhos quero é os filhos da box a cada 3 passe para a row de baixo e tenha uma margem entre eles 8/5px, e a margem de "fora" seja 10/ 20 px relativamente à row maior. Isto tudo de forma dinâmica.

Answer (score 4):

Vou te dar uma solução que é a mais atual em nível de css, ela usa `display:grid`. Existem até outras formas de conseguir esse layout, mas não de forma tão simples e dinâmica como vc quer.

Repare na imagem abaixo, veja que usei um `padding` no *container* para dar o espaçamento `acima/abaixo 20px` e na `direita/esquerda 10px`, entre os `.box` eu usei a propriedade do grid chamado `grid-gap` repare que no `gap` eu coloquei `8px de espaçamento horizontal` e `5px de espaçamento vertical` entre um e outro. Repare na imagem que com o `display:grid` os espaçamento ficam apenas entre os `.box`, e não se somam a outros valores do `grid`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu defini o númeno de colunas aqui `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);` dessa forma cada uma das colunas sempre terá 1fr. Aqui tem uma documentação básica da Mozilla sobre o **Grid Layout**, acho que vai te ajudar: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout

Seque o código referente a imagem acima, deixei os comentário no código para te ajudar a entender melhor como o `grid` funciona

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  display: grid;
  /* aqui eu determino é são 3 colunas de tamanhos iguas, cada coluna tem uma fração */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  /* esssa é a altura das linhas, se vc quiser pode apaga-la caso não queira uma altura definida */
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  /* espaço entre um elemento interno e outro */
  grid-gap: 5px 8px;
  /* margem interna que afasta os elementos da borda do grid */
  padding: 20px 10px;
}
.box {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
  <div class="box">7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

[image: resultado do código]

Não sei se ainda vai ser útil mas acho que talvez possa ajudar outras pessoas, caso queira usar especificamente o flex, por algum motivo específico, ficou assim minha solução:

```
.wrapper{
    background: blue;
    width: 336px;
    height: 245px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.flex{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}
.box{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
.m-8{
    margin: 0 8px;
}
.linha2{
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.box{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```
<div class="wrapper flex">
    <div class="container">
        
        <div class="linha1 flex">
            <div class="box">Box1</div>
            <div class="box m-8">Box2</div>
            <div class="box">Box3</div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="linha2 flex">
            <div class="box">Box4</div>
            <div class="box m-8">Box5</div>
            <div class="box">Box6</div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</div>
```